# onSelect event handler typescript type for react bootstrap DropDown

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I use React with typescript and react-bootstrap to create dropdown list:

```
ipc__handleSelect = (eventKey: any, event: any) => {
}

render() {

    return (
        <Dropdown>
            <Dropdown.Toggle>Text</Dropdown.Toggle>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item
                    key         = 'key1'
                    eventKey    = 'key1'
                    onSelect    = {this.ipc__handleSelect}
                >Item</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    );
}
```

help identify data types

1. `event: any` - what type should I write?
2. `eventKey: any` - what type should I write?

when I write `eventKey: string` (because the key is a string), I get error:

> Type '(eventKey: string, event: any) => void' is not assignable to
> type 'SelectCallback'.         Types of parameters 'eventKey' and
> 'eventKey' are incompatible.
> Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
> Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.

why does `null` even occur there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the react-bootstrap library code, you will see that Dropdown. Item has an onSelect of type SelectCallback and SelectCallback is like this:

```js
export type SelectCallback = (
  eventKey: string | null,
  e: React.SyntheticEvent<unknown>,
) => void;
```

Since you assign that your handler took in only string type and Dropdown Item onSelect gives string|null to eventKey, you got an error that it cannot be mapped.

Comment: If I write `eventKey: string | null` then an error is displayed `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'`, if wite `event: React.SyntheticEvent<unknown>` - error: `Property 'className' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.` when use `event.target.className` in `handleSelect`

Comment: I don't get the first error where it said `Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'` when I tried it, what version of react-bootstrap and typescript are you using? For the second one, since the type of event.target is EventTarget, for you to get HTML attributes, you have to cast it to HTMLElement like this `(event.target as HTMLElement).className`